# an adult's responding to a child's sneeze with a blessing, or vice versa

Tags: halacha, blessing, minor-katan-child, health-safety-shmira

The halacha states ([Mishnah Brurah 230: 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=285&hilite=)) that one should respond to a sneeze with a blessing and the person who sneezed and was blessed should return with a blessing in kind. this is not done if you are engaged in torah study. does this halacha apply to equally between an adult and a child, meaning if an adult hears a child sneeze does he need to give a blessing and vise versa?

Comment: Related: [Saying “Laberiut” “God bless you” or “Gesundheit”](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/saying-laberiut-god-bless-you-or-gesundheit)

Comment: You may wish to edit into your question why you think it might not apply to a child.