# Jewish responses to a sneeze

Tags: blessing, words

I have heard la'briut and gezuntheit, and a Sephardic (Lebanese) Jew recently taught me 'tai-shi'.

What are other words or phrases which are used to respond when someone sneezes?

Comment: Related: _[Jewish responses to a sneeze](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12587/70)_.

Answer (score 7):

I was taught to say “*asusa*” ([אסותא](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%90)), from the Aramaic word for “health”. (אסיא = doctor)

לבריאות *labriut* and געזונטהייט *gezuntheit* (or צום געזונט *tzum gezunt*) mean the same thing—“to health!” in Hebrew and Yiddish.

Answer (score 5):

In the interest of collecting more sneeze-responses, I'll add that the Rambam (Hil. Talmud Torah 4:9) indicates that one says 'רפואה', though his source is the Tosefta Shabbos 8:2 where our version reads 'מרפא'. (It's all the same idea, referring to health)

In the interest of interesting things, there's [a book published on the halachos of sneezing](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-okaZ0Wdqt_E/UD2PkpkkO6I/AAAAAAAAAck/vwMEHGrzhZQ/s1600/Hoffman.JPG), which [this Maariv news article](http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4258883,00.html) thought was noteworthy (or at least funny).