# Am I obligated to say "bless you" (or its equivalent) after someone sneezes?

Tags: halacha, tractate-brachot, health-safety-shmira

The Midrash Pirkei D'Rebbi Eliezer (54) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.52.6?vhe=Pirkei_Derabi_Eliezer&lang=bi)

> המופת הרביעי, מיום שנברא העולם לא היה אדם חולה, אלא בכל מקום שהיה אדם
> אם בדרך אם בשוק ועטש היתה נפשו יוצאה מנחיריו ומת, עד שבא יעקב אבינו
> ובקש רחמים על זאת ואמר לפני הב"ה, רבונו של עולם אל תקח את נפשי ממני עד
> אשר אני מצוה את בני ובני ביתי. ונעתר לו, שנ' ויהי אחרי הדברים האלה
> ויאמר ליוסף הנה אביך חולה. ושמעו כל מלכי הארץ ותמהו שלא היה כמהו מיום
> שנבראו שמים וארץ, לפיכך **חייב אדם לומר לחבירו בשעת עטישותיו** חיים שנהפך
> מות העולם לאור, שנ' (איוב מא, י) עטישותיו תהל אור - The fourth wonder
> (was): From the day when the heavens and the earth were created no man
> was ill, (who) sneezed and lived, but in every place where he happened
> to be, whether on the way or in the market, and (when he) sneezed, his
> soul went out through his nostrils; until our father Jacob came and
> prayed for mercy concerning this, and he said before the Holy One,
> blessed be He: Sovereign of all the worlds! Do not take my soul from
> me until I have charged my sons and my household; and He was entreated
> of him, as it is said, "And it came to pass after these things, that
> one said to Joseph, Behold, thy father is sick" (Gen. 48:1). || All
> the kings of the earth heard (thereof), and they wondered because
> there had been no one like him from the days when the heavens and
> earth had been created. **Therefore a man is in duty bound to say to his
> fellow: Life! when the latter sneezes,** for the death of the world was
> changed into light, as it is said, "His neesings flash forth light"
> (Job 41:18).

On the other hand, Rashi in Berachos (53a) [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Berakhot.53a.25.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi)

> מרפא – לאדם המתעטש שרגילים לומר אסותא. Rabban Gamliel wouldn't say "to health!" in the Beis Midrash, the way that people normally say "Health!"

which seems to imply that it was just a common practice of people rather than a requirement.

Finally, there is a Tosefta Shabbos (8:2) which actually [forbids](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Shabbat.8.2?vhe=Tosefta_Shabbat&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) this due to Darkei Emori:

> האומר מרפא הרי זה מדרכי האמורי ר' אלעזר ברבי צדוק אומר [אין אומרים
> מרפא מפני ביטול תורה של בית ר"ג] לא היו אומרים מרפא [מפני דרכי האמורי]

Do Poskim codify a requirement to say "Bless you!", "Health!", or its equivalent when someone sneezes? (Shulchan Aruch OC 170:1 [poskins](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.170.1?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) not to say "Bless you" during a meal, but that doesn't necessarily show one is required to do so otherwise)

Comment: See 230:4 with beir heitiv

Comment: @DoubleAA Your bekius never ceases to amaze me - the Be'er Heitev doesn't seem to lean one way or another, more "One who sneezes and his friend says, bless you then respond..." - מי שמתעטש וחבירו א''ל אסותא - rather than saying "He should 'bless you'. Did you read it differently?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12587/13811

Comment: @doubleaa, why not the MB 230:7

Comment: @sam That's not where I remembered it from, and anyway mine is the MB's source

Comment: Here's the original source https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40932&st=&pgnum=184